# Does destroying your only sleeping bag when logged out cause death?

Tags: rust

Last night, I was in my wooden shelter with a wooden door, cooking some chicken. A couple guys saw my fire and started hitting my door with what sounded like basic stones. I grabbed my meager amount of loot from my storage box and logged off for the night (it was late and fighting them would have gotten me nothing).

When I logged in this morning, I spawned in a random location with no gear.

Did this happen because they destroyed my only sleeping bag? Was my character still in the game after I had logged out and they killed me? I assume it would have taken them another 2-5 minutes to break through the door.

This occurred on Feb 6, 2014 (in case the build version matters).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Destroying your sleeping bag does not kill your character.

However, when you log out, **your body is still in the game**, lying face-first on the floor.

If someone hits your unconscious body a few times with a rock, they will kill you and you will lose all your gear.  The next time you log in, you'll wake up with the starting gear at your sleeping bag, or at a random location if they destroyed that too.

Comment: Wow, that's terrible.  I find it odd that I have never found an unconscious player before.  Does your character ever disappear?  Is there a good mitigation strategy to keep your body from being found?

Comment: Hide behind lots of metal doors and hope for the best

Comment: Or hide in a rock crevasse in the mountains ... and hope for the best :)

Comment: Sleeper is the term used to describe a sleeping character. Every character leaves a sleeper unless the admin turns the feature off. When sleepers are enabled the character lays on the floor a solid 24 hours before disappearing.